# The Adventures of Jack #3

Tags: riddle, wordplay, story, geography, chemistry

He's back at it again!

> 'Twas the night before Christmas,
>
> And Jack only wanted one thing.
>
> A hat - what else would he need?
>
> Jack thought about colours, possibly crimson.
>
> But the way he was - he'd likely get crismon...
>
> So where is Jack celebrating his festive season?

Enjoy!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'Twas the night before Christmas,

> *eve*

And Jack only wanted one thing. A hat - what else would he need?

> Put a cap on to get *capeve*

Jack thought about colours, possibly crimson. But the way he was - he'd likely get crimson...

> Possibly red, but if he became crimson, perhaps turn red to rde, these giving *capeverde*.

So he may be celebrating his festive season in

> **Cape Verde** (doesn't explain the [chemistry](/questions/tagged/chemistry) tag except that close to [christmas](/questions/tagged/christmas))

Comment: Well done, this is the intended answer. God, people are getting these so quickly! Anyway, the chemistry tag is on because the two previous puzzles had elements of chemistry. hahaha...